# jQuery time left until ... setInterval not working

Tags: jquery

I am learning to work with dates and I am a little confused.

I am trying to calculate the months: days : hours : mins : secs left until another date.

I am close, but I am stuck on the updating the time left every second, why is my setInterval not updating every 1 sec?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

var currentDate = new Date();
var futureDate = new Date(2016, 08, 07 , 14 , 33, 20);

  //display current and future date
$('#currentDate').text( currentDate);
$('#futureDate').text(futureDate);   
  
  
   //count down 
var countDown = setInterval(function() {
   var timeLeft = new Date();
   timeLeft = futureDate - currentDate;
      var seconds= Math.floor((timeLeft/1000)%60);
   var minutes= Math.floor((timeLeft/(1000*60))%60);
   var hours= Math.floor((timeLeft/(1000*60*60))%24);
   var dayz= Math.floor((timeLeft/(1000*60*60*24))%31);
      $('#timeLeft').text(dayz + " " + hours + " " + minutes + " " + seconds);
      //return  (dayz + " " + hours + " " + minutes + " " + seconds);
}, 1000);
 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Current Date: <span id="currentDate"></span><br/>
Future Date: <span id="futureDate"></span><br/>
Time till: <span id="timeLeft"></span><br/>
```

Comment: var seconds= Math.floor((timeLeft/1000)%60);

Comment: Yep, sorry misread due to the slightly weird formatting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define `currentDate` to be the current `Date()`, not `timeLeft`:

```
var currentDate = new Date();
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var currentDate = new Date();
  var futureDate = new Date(2016, 08, 07, 14, 33, 20);

  //display current and future date
  $('#currentDate').text(currentDate);
  $('#futureDate').text(futureDate);

  //count down 
  var countDown = setInterval(function() {
    var currentDate = new Date(); // < change this variable's name
    var timeLeft = futureDate - currentDate;
    var seconds = Math.floor((timeLeft / 1000) % 60);
    var minutes = Math.floor((timeLeft / (1000 * 60)) % 60);
    var hours = Math.floor((timeLeft / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);
    var dayz = Math.floor((timeLeft / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) % 31);
    $('#timeLeft').text(dayz + " " + hours + " " + minutes + " " + seconds);
    //return  (dayz + " " + hours + " " + minutes + " " + seconds);
  }, 1000);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Current Date: <span id="currentDate"></span>
<br/>Future Date: <span id="futureDate"></span>
<br/>Time till: <span id="timeLeft"></span>
<br/>
```

Comment: AH! The current date was static because it was outside the setInterval!! Gosh I am such a fool! THANK YOU!!!!

Comment: No problem, glad to help. For reference, the current date was set inside the loop, but you were never using it as it was immediately overwritten